# Is This Company Legitimate? Bivavo Store

Tags: scams, gift-card

I recently saw advertised on `eBay` (UK) a company called Bivavo (bivavo.store), offering gift cards for `eBay` at roughly 1/3rd off, in both `£` and `€`. They have a fair number of gift cards -- eg `eBay`, `Amazon`, `Apple Store`.

I cannot, however, find out any information about this company. They also offer `Toys 'R' Us` cards... which I thought were out of business, but maybe not.... Also, they accept `Visa` and `MasterCard` credit cards.

On their `About Us` page there is some Russian (I believe): `iTunes и App Store`.
On their `Payment and delivery` page, it says "Payment for goods is carried out through the CHBILL.COM service".

Upon clicking `purchase` (without having entered any card details!), one is sent to `bivavo.store/payment.php` (no https). (See image below.)
Checking the locations of the images, they are on a website `bloomchain.ru` (with `https`, but no padlock).

I do buy a fair amount on eBay and so would appreciate the 1/3rd off! I both want to be careful, but also not just discard a potentially good option without thought. Currently I'm strongly leaning towards `no`.

If I were to purchase using a credit card, would I have protection from my credit card provider?

[image]

Comment: Looks super shady. My guess is that the gift cards are stolen or obtained through scamming people and now they are converting them into money by selling them to you.

Comment: This is my feeling too. My general motto is `if it looks too good to be true, then it probably is!`

Comment: Even though the website footer states a copyright date of "2013-2020", the domain name was only registered on the 4th of June 2020. The fact that this domain was registered so recently makes it even more suspicious indeed.

Comment: On another page, it says "2013-2018". I think it's safe to say that there's something very shady going ong!

Comment: Please don't use code markup `like this` for emphasis. It confuses screen readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I were to purchase using a credit card, would I have protection from my credit card provider?

[This blogger has some general rules](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/best-cards-purchase-protection/) and the answer seems to be no:

> Types of purchases often excluded: Motorized vehicles and their parts, animals, living plants, perishable or consumable items, tickets, **gift cards**, antiques, jewelry, medical equipment

Your own credit card may vary, read the details of the protection plan.

If you have to be worrying about purchase protection before a deal is made, that seems like a strong signal to not proceed with the deal. The goal of protection and insurance is to have it, but not actually need it.

[Toys 'R' Us is almost defunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toys_%22R%22_Us), with only a few outlets in Britain, Canada, and France. A site advertising gift cards for a defunct or significantly shrunk outlet is suspicious. At a bare minimum they haven't kept up with what gift cards are marketable to their customers.

Finally - Gift cards are often available at a discount. The premise being that people will buy the cards but never use them and that the end-vendor and intermediate seller both get cash now but don't have to pay the value of the cards until later. Is this site offering discounts that are in line with other sellers? If they are - then find a more legitimate seller. If this sites discounts are deeper - then how are they offering a better deal than their competitors?

I would say that this company is not legitimate.

Comment: Toys R Us is still a going concern in Canada.